# How to regard negative PSH function with neat analytic singularities as a generalization of Green-type function?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

I am reading this paper:A SIMPLIFIED PROOF OF OPTIMAL L2-EXTENSION THEOREM AND EXTENSIONS FROM NON-REDUCED SUBVARIETIES by Hosono. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1910.05782.pdf.

The setting is as follows.Let $\Omega\subset\subset\mathbb C^n$ be a bounded pseudoconvex domain and $V\subset \Omega$ be a closed submanifold.The **Green-type function** $G$ on $\Omega$ with poles along $V$ is defined by :$G\in PSH(\Omega)$,$G<0$ on $\Omega$,and for some continuous functions $A$ and $B$ on $\Omega$,

$$\log d^2(z,V)+A(z)\leq G(z)\leq \log d^2(z,V)-B(z).$$

In the same time,$\psi$ is **a negative PSH function on $\Omega$ with neat analytic singularities**,i.e. for each point $x\in\Omega$,there exist a neighborhood $U$ of $x$, a positive number $c>0$,a finite number of holomorphic functions $g_1,...,g_N\in\mathcal O(U)$,and a smooth function $u\in C^\infty (U)$ s.t.

$$\psi(z)=c\log (|g_1(z)|^2+...+|g_N(z)|^2)+u(z)$$

for $z\in U$.

Then he says,we will regard $\psi$ as a generalition of Green-type functions $G$ in page 5.I mean，how to comprehend this sentence？For $\psi$,can I find explicit $A(z),B(z)$?